# Getting ECS Docker container meta-data failed?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have the following code and it runs in EC2.

```
import requests

def get_aws_account_id():
    try:
        url = 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info/'
        print(url)
        x = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
        print(f'x: {x.json()}')  # didn't print
        return x.json()['InstanceProfileArn'].split(':')[4]
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"exception ==> {e}")
        return None
```

However, it gets the following exception when running in one of the docker container of ECS (EC2, not fargate)? The same code runs fine in another docker container of ECS.

```
exception ==> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What does the Dockerfile look like?

Comment: ECS tasks have a different metadata endpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html

Comment: @MarkB, yes, tested `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4` and it works. Interesting, the function used to work (GET `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info/` in ECS container). It stopped working a few days ago.

Comment: Did you change anything about the networking settings in the task definition?

Comment: I didn't. Not sure if anyone else made some changes. It seems some of other services which use the 169.254.169.254 are still running.

Comment: Just tried the code in another Container in ECS. And it works.